# Remove Whitespaces from html sourcecode by php

Tags: php, replace

```
<ul class="c2">
    <li><a href="hire-project-manager/">Hire Project Manager </a></li>
    <li><a href="hire-ios-developer/"> Hire iPhone Developer </a></li>
    <li><a href="hire-ios-developer/">  Hire iPad Developer </a></li>
    <li><a href="hire-android-developer/">Hire Android Developer </a></li>
    </li>
    <li><a href="hire-3d-artist/">Hire 3D Artist</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<h1>Get In Touch With Us</h1>
<div class="copyright-footer">Copyright &copy; All rights reserved  </div>
```

I have following of these html and i want to remove extra spaces and need result something like:

```
<ul class="c2">
    <li><a href="hire-project-manager/">Hire Project Manager</a></li>
    <li><a href="hire-ios-developer/">Hire iPhone Developer</a></li>
    <li><a href="hire-ios-developer/">Hire iPad Developer</a></li>
    <li><a href="hire-android-developer/">Hire Android Developer</a></li>
    </li>
    <li><a href="hire-3d-artist/">Hire 3D Artist</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<h1>Get In Touch With Us</h1>
<div class="copyright-footer">Copyright &copy; All rights reserved</div>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this with the help of PHP and preg, str_replace etc

Comment: That moment when Markdown automatically corrects the extra whitespaces ini your question...

Comment: I'll do your code work if you do my ironing.

Comment: I edited your answer using `tidy` which seems to have obscured the question (but I didn't see any difference between the two blocks to begin with).  So maybe your answer is `tidy`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

Comment: I couldn't tell if this was spam or not.

Comment: @ExplosionPills You modified the question the wrong way! You should have just put the html in code. The tidy result you could post in your answer! People are thinking that he is spamming or ironing, but he isn't.

Comment: @falsarella I rolled my edit back

Comment: @ExplosionPills Again, the revision 3 seems the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove whitespace `[\n\t\r\ ]` from the start of text after tag start:

```
$html=preg_replace('/>\s+/','>',$html);
```

Remove whitespace `[\n\t\r\ ]` from the end of text before a tag:

```
$html=preg_replace('/\s+</','<',$html);
```

Comment: That type of question will always end one way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1064325

Comment: It's just about whitespace @falsarella, regex is great for this. Of course you could use a built in parser to disassemble the html, trim the text and patch it back together but that would be an overkill just for this.

Comment: And if you have something like this `<code><span>' > < '</span></code>`? Inspecting your answer, you can see a live sample. But, probably your answer will fit to the OP's needs!